# Unable to configure the Verify Privilege Vault Software Development Kit for DevOps

Tags: ansible, rhel8

I am running a RHEL 8 server, trying to utilise the SDK for Privilege Vault.

I am following the instructions to install the SDK Secret Server Scripting Tool for DevOps ([click here](https://ibm.docs.delinea.com/online-help/products/isvp-vault/current/api-scripting/sdk-downloads/index.md#red_hat_enterprise_linux_6_x64)) on the Linux server but running into an issue when trying to initialise the Client. I am getting the following error:

> Failed to load x�Z, error: libunwind.so.8: cannot open shared object file:
>
> No such file or directory Failed to bind to CoreCLR at '/var/lib/tss/libcoreclr.so'

The issue appears to be related to the libunwind missing. But when I try to install that package, I am getting the following error:

> Last metadata expiration check: 2:20:23 ago on Wed 21 Dec 2022 08:00:44 AM EST.
>
> No match for argument: libunwind

Is there something obvious I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link below led me to the resolution, which was to install OpenSSL v1.0 via `sudo dnf install compat-openssl10 libaio`:

https://access.redhat.com/discussions/6314751